# Why PyPI(Python Package Index) search result doesn't contain latest version?

Tags: python, pypi, isbnlib

Latest version of isbnlib is 3.5.8 according to google search result,
and that version fully accessible on official PyPI site with this [link](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbnlib/3.5.8).

but pip search and manual search on PyPI site [result](https://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=isbnlib&submit=search) only give me up to one version before, 3.5.7.

Please explain something about it.
Thanks!

Comment: isbnlib v 3.5.8 works file for me.What version of python are you using

Comment: @jithin Thanks but resolved already, It's working fine weirdly on setup.py install requires, python 3.5.1 venv + setuptools is my current dev environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Package authors submit packages to PyPI (the Python Package Index). So PyPi is not in charge of keeping the latest version. But it is very easy to find downloads for [3.5.8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbnlib/3.5.8#downloads) then click downloads. Also, you could download it from [github](https://github.com/xlcnd/isbnlib) and install it yourself.

Comment: I guess 'submit package' is handy process, right? and authors didn't submit yet.  
  
how about this [page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/isbnlib/3.5.8)?

I think it's painful if manually write this page, I think almost automatically generated but need little handwork.  

Is that right?  
Thanks!

Comment: I've never uploaded a package, but yes that package site should be autogenerated. Here is a tutorial https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/distributing/#uploading-your-project-to-pypi

Answer (score 1):

This is one of many bugs on pypi... you can follow it as [issue #466](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/pypi/issues/466)